# How to clean and organize Eclipse Package Explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, package

Could you give me some advice to organize Package Explorer?

I have many closed projects and sometimes I have a lot of close projects between the projects that I have to work on it.

There are some plugin or anything to organize projects in folders or something similar?

Comment: I have seen android projects (library, demo, test etc) all in one folder. That's how it sgould be. Yet I have not found a way to do it myself in eclipse.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for working sets?

[Eclipse working sets](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cworkset.htm) (version for Eclipse 3.6, Helios)

[Eclipse working sets](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcworkset.htm) (version for current Eclipse release 4.2, Juno)

Comment: Exactly :-) sorry, I'm very new in eclipse

Answer (score 27):

In the drop down menu of Package Explorer, you can select Filters and choose Closed Projects. This will automatically hide all the projects that are closed.

Comment: There is no Filters option in Eclipse 4.6.3 (Neon.3)

Answer (score 5):

Using working sets is an easy built-in way. The key to make it organized is to open the Package Explorer’s View Menu again and enable Top Level Elements > Working Sets.
Then the projects are grouped by working set visually in the package explorer.

Answer (score 3):

In response to "In the drop down menu of Package Explorer, you can select Filters and choose Closed Projects. This will automatically hide all the projects that are closed."

Don't forget to right-click on the project and select close project. If you don't do this, it will not 'automatically hide'.

I.e. the filter excludes closed projects, you must first set a project as closed by right-clicking on it in the Package Explorer and select Close Project.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having a different workspace for each cluster of projects, if you can cluster them together in some way. An advantage is that you can then have several Eclipse applications running at the same time on different workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

As say Kaj the working set are a good way for organizate your eclipse projects.

You can create a multiples working set. In the upper left corner in the package explorer there is a many options with the working set.

.. Select working set. Can you add new, edit and remove.
.. Deselect working set. 
.. Edit active working set

Also, you have a option to organize the projects by working set. This means that the top element are the working set.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the 3 dots in Package Explorer menu.
2. Filters.
3. Select the 'Closed projects'
4. Right click on the project you want to close and choose Closed projects.

Tip: You can add or remove other filters with the 3. step.